# Find out the closest value PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe having the following columns

`'CUSTOMER_ID','ORDERED_TIME','ORDER_ID'`

Here, `ORDERED_TIME` is a timestamp field indicating when the order was placed, `CUSTOMER_ID` is the customer id (INTEGER) and `ORDER_ID` is the order_id (INTEGER)

Now, from this dataframe, for every order made in the month of **Jan to March 2021**, I need to find out the time the previous order was placed **just before** `ORDERED_TIME`. Let's call this column `PREV_ORDER_TIME`

The dataframe includes order data all the way back to 2019. However, I am only computing `PREV_ORDER_TIME` for all orders made **between Jan to March**. If there is no `PREV_ORDER_TIME` order for an order, I would like to display `null`

My final expected output is something like  `['CUSTOMER_ID','ORDERED_TIME','ORDER_ID','PREV_ORDER_TIME']`

The way I understand, for some orders in these 3 months, the previous orders can be in these 3 months, but for some other orders, it may well be before this window.

I am not sure how to approach this. I feel like I might need to use some binary search to find the closest date, but am not really sure how to make this work only for orders from Jan to March despite my dataset containing orders well before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`lag`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lag.html) function over a [window](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window), as follow:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

window = Window().partitionBy("CUSTOMER_ID").orderBy('ORDERED_TIME')

dataframe.withColumn('PREV_ORDER_TIME', F.lag('ORDERED_TIME').over(window))
```

If there is no previous order, column `PREV_ORDER_TIME` will be `null`

And if you want to compute this `PREV_ORDER_TIME` column only for date between 2021-01-01 and 2021-03-31, you can add a [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when) clause, as follow:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

window = Window().partitionBy("CUSTOMER_ID").orderBy('ORDERED_TIME')

dataframe.withColumn(
  'PREV_ORDER_TIME', 
  F.when(
    (F.col('ORDERED_TIME') < datetime(2021, 4, 1)) & (F.col('ORDERED_TIME') >= datetime(2021, 1, 1)),
    F.lag('ORDERED_TIME').over(window)
  )
)
```

For all orders when date is not between 2021-01-01 and 2021-03-31, column `PREV_ORDER_TIME` will be `null`

So if you have the following input dataframe:

```
+-----------+--------+-------------------+
|CUSTOMER_ID|ORDER_ID|ORDERED_TIME       |
+-----------+--------+-------------------+
|1          |21      |2019-12-15 10:20:30|
|1          |22      |2020-12-16 11:21:31|
|1          |23      |2021-01-17 12:22:32|
|2          |24      |2021-01-18 13:23:33|
|2          |25      |2021-02-19 14:24:34|
|2          |26      |2021-03-20 15:25:35|
+-----------+--------+-------------------+
```

You will get the following output:

```
+-----------+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
|CUSTOMER_ID|ORDER_ID|ORDERED_TIME       |PREV_ORDER_TIME    |
+-----------+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
|1          |21      |2019-12-15 10:20:30|null               |
|1          |22      |2020-12-16 11:21:31|null               |
|1          |23      |2021-01-17 12:22:32|2020-12-16 11:21:31|
|2          |24      |2021-01-18 13:23:33|null               |
|2          |25      |2021-02-19 14:24:34|2021-01-18 13:23:33|
|2          |26      |2021-03-20 15:25:35|2021-02-19 14:24:34|
+-----------+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new today. The lag and sort combination was really nice. Just to clarify, apart from those orders that have no previous order, for those orders that are not in this window (like if it was placed in Dec 2020 but still have a prev order), the prev_order_time will be null even for those right?

Comment: @JiteshMalipeddi Yes, it will be `null`. I added an example to my answer to clarify that.

Comment: FYI, using `datetime.date(2021, 4, 1))` instead of `datetime(2021, 4, 1)` worked for me